# text/ input not showing up in div

Tags: html, css

so i am practicing building and incremental game and while trying to develop the web page, i run into this problem...
here is link to webpage i am working on http://47z.bitballoon.com/

---

```css
#header{
 margin: auto;
}

#points{
 margin: auto;
 border: 3px solid green;
}

#points_per_second{
 margin: auto;
 border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

 <head>
 
  <title>Incremental Game Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="http://aldo111.github.io/incremental-game-engine-js/js/incrementalObject.js"></script>
  <script src="http://aldo111.github.io/incremental-game-engine-js/js/jquery.js"></script>
  
 <!--Our Javascript Code-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
  
 //Variable Declarations & Initializations
  var game;
 
 
 //the init() function initializes or sets up our game
 function init()
 {
  game=new Game(28);
   game.addAttribute("Points",0);
    game.track("Points","#points", function(value) { return value.toFixed(0); });
   game.addAttribute("PointsPerSecond",0);
    game.track("PointsPerSecond","#points_per_second")
  
  game.addClicker("#earn",function() { 
   game.attributes.Points+=2;
   game.addClickerText("+2");//adds clicker/particle text - still under works!
  });
  
  game.addClicker("#getSome", function() {
  //this function also shows another way to access attributes
  var p=game.getAttribute("Points");
  var cost=10;
  var increase=2;
 
   if (p>=cost)
  {
   //we can buy
    p-=cost;
    game.setAttribute("Points",p);
    var pps=game.getAttribute("PointsPerSecond");
    pps+=increase;
    game.setAttribute("PointsPerSecond",pps);
  }
  
 
 
 
});
   
  game.play(play);//Tells the Game() object's play() function that we want to execute the code in our play() function for every loop iteration in the game loop
 }
 
 //the play() function contains essential game code
 function play() 
 {
  var g=game.attributes;
  g["Points"]+=g["PointsPerSecond"]/game.getFPS(); 
  
 }
 
 //this checks if the window has loaded - includes the document, and all objects/elements in it - and executes the function init() when it has
  window.onload=init;
  
  </script>
  
  
 </head>
 
 <body>
 <div id='header'>
  <h1><center>Incremental Game Test</h1>
 </div>
 <div id='points'>
 Points: <span id="points"></span>
 <input type='button' id='earn' value='Earn Points'>
 </div>
 
 <div id='points_per_second'>
 Points Per Second: <span id="points_per_second"></span>
 <input type='button' id='getSome' value='Get Some!'>
 </div>
 
 </body>
 
</html>
```

why is the text and the input button not showing up on the final website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are assigning 2 same IDs for `points` and `points_per_second`, while JavaScript pick only the one ID. Just make 1 `Points` ID and 1 `points_per_second` ID like the following:

```
<div class='points'>
    Points: <span id="points"></span>
    <input type='button' id='earn' value='Earn Points'>
</div>

<div class='points_per_second'>
    Points Per Second: <span id="points_per_second"></span>
    <input type='button' id='getSome' value='Get Some!'>
</div>
```

To solve this issue you have to make only one ID. I have updated your code and here is working example.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Incremental Game Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #header{
                margin: auto;
            }

            #points{
                margin: auto;
                border: 3px solid green;
            }

            #points_per_second{
                margin: auto;
                border: 3px solid green;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://aldo111.github.io/incremental-game-engine-js/js/incrementalObject.js"></script>
        <script src="http://aldo111.github.io/incremental-game-engine-js/js/jquery.js"></script>

        <!--Our Javascript Code-->
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Variable Declarations & Initializations
            var game;


            //the init() function initializes or sets up our game
            function init()
            {
                game=new Game(28);
                    game.addAttribute("Points",0);
                        game.track("Points","#points", function(value) { return value.toFixed(0); });
                    game.addAttribute("PointsPerSecond",0);
                        game.track("PointsPerSecond","#points_per_second")

                game.addClicker("#earn",function() { 
                    game.attributes.Points+=2;
                    game.addClickerText("+2");//adds clicker/particle text - still under works!
                });

                game.addClicker("#getSome", function() {
                    //this function also shows another way to access attributes
                    var p=game.getAttribute("Points");
                    var cost=10;
                    var increase=2;

                        if (p>=cost)
                    {
                        //we can buy
                            p-=cost;
                            game.setAttribute("Points",p);
                            var pps=game.getAttribute("PointsPerSecond");
                            pps+=increase;
                            game.setAttribute("PointsPerSecond",pps);
                    }
                });

                game.play(play);//Tells the Game() object's play() function that we want to execute the code in our play() function for every loop iteration in the game loop
            }

            //the play() function contains essential game code
            function play() 
            {
                var g=game.attributes;
                g["Points"]+=g["PointsPerSecond"]/game.getFPS(); 

            }
            //this checks if the window has loaded - includes the document, and all objects/elements in it - and executes the function init() when it has
            window.onload=init;
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id='header'>
        <h1><center>Incremental Game Test</h1>
    </div>
    <div class='points'>
        Points: <span id="points"></span>
        <input type='button' id='earn' value='Earn Points'>
    </div>

    <div class='points_per_second'>
        Points Per Second: <span id="points_per_second"></span>
        <input type='button' id='getSome' value='Get Some!'>
    </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: one more question, because when i paste your code it works fine but when i make the changes myself it doesnt so did you change anything else other than the div containers classes?

Comment: No, I just changed the containers ID into classes.

Rest of the code is exactly same